# How to compare two dates in different formats in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this array with days:

```
var dates = [
    /* 2016 */
    "October 28, 2016","November 17, 2016","December 24, 2016","December 25, 2016","December 26, 2016",
    /* 2017 */
    "January 1, 2017","March 3, 2017","April 17, 2017","May 1, 2017","May 8, 2017","July 5, 2017","July 6, 2017","September 28, 2017","October 28, 2017","November 17,2017","December 24, 2017","December 25, 2017","December 26, 2017"
]
```

and I want them compare with tomorrow's date, so I created variable for tomorrow

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow .setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
tomorrow .setHours(0);
tomorrow .setMinutes(0);
tomorrow .setSeconds(0);
tomorrow .setMilliseconds(0);
```

When I try to `dates.indexOf(tomorrow)` I get result `-1`.

Value of `tomorrow` is `Fri Oct 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Střední Evropa (letní čas))`

---

**EDIT:** I changed my dates array to

```
var dates = [
    /* 2016 */
    new Date("October 28, 2016"), new Date("November 17, 2016"), new Date("December 24, 2016"), new Date("December 25, 2016"), new Date ("December 26, 2016"),
    /* 2017 */
    new Date("January 1, 2017"), new Date("March 3, 2017"), new Date("April 17, 2017"), new Date("May 1, 2017"), new Date("May 8, 2017"), new Date("July 5, 2017"), new Date("July 6, 2017"), new Date("September 28, 2017"), new Date("October 28, 2017"), new Date("November 17,2017"), new Date("December 24, 2017"), new Date("December 25, 2017"), new Date("December 26, 2017")
]
```

and now when I compare `tomorrow`'s value which is `Fri Oct 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Střední Evropa (letní čas))` with function `dates.indexOf(tomorrow)`, I still get `-1` result.

`dates[0]` value is `Fri Oct 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Střední Evropa (letní čas))`

`tomorrow`'s value is `Fri Oct 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Střední Evropa (letní čas))`

It's same, why the result is not `0`?

Comment: You could do this with pure javascript, but date handling in javascript isn't simple,.. There are libs like http://momentjs.com/ that make doing this much easier.

Comment: Your dates array is an array of text. I would suggest you google how to work with dates in javascript.

Comment: Not related to the question, but instead of manually creating a new date every time, you can use the `.map()` function to make life a bit easier. Example: `var dates = [/* Dates as string. */].map(function(d){return new Date(d)})`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a date variable like this:

```
var date = new Date("October 28, 2016")
```

Take a look at [JavaScript Date Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

in your code, instead of `tomorrow .setDate(zitrek.getDate() + 1);` you should have `tomorrow .setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);`

EDIT
To transform the dates array into dates variables, you just need to call a cycle ("for", "while") or a map to read from your array, like so:

```
var dates = [
    /* 2016 */
    "October 28, 2016","November 17, 2016","December 24, 2016","December 25, 2016","December 26, 2016",
    /* 2017 */
    "January 1, 2017","March 3, 2017","April 17, 2017","May 1, 2017","May 8, 2017","July 5, 2017","July 6, 2017","September 28, 2017","October 28, 2017","November 17,2017","December 24, 2017","December 25, 2017","December 26, 2017"
];

//define your dates array and tomorrow var before this
//... now we use the dates array
for(var i = 0; i<dates.length; i++){ //dates.length is the size of your array
    var temp_date = new Date(dates[i]);
    console.log(dates[i]);   //your strings
    console.log(temp_date);  //your date from the strings
    //... do calculations here with temp_date
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it.

Comment: for the second line of tomorrow .setDate(zitrek), it was just a typo, I translated my code from czech to english and forgot to translate one variable. Now its fixed in my question. :)

Comment: Check my update, instead of `zitrek` that is not defined, you should use `tomorow`. EDIT: OK

Comment: Would you mind checking my edit to the question. Thank you.